# Exception initializer

Tags: java, tomcat, classloader, pkcs#11

I wrote a dynamic web project with Java. I deployed to tomcat.
When I make the first call there is no problem, it runs properly.
On the second call, the error below occurred.
After restarting tomcat it runs properly again.

I want every call to run properly.
How can I solve this problem.

Best regards.

```
import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.StringReader;
import java.io.StringWriter;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Properties;

import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;
import javax.xml.soap.MessageFactory;
import javax.xml.soap.SOAPConnection;
import javax.xml.soap.SOAPConnectionFactory;
import javax.xml.soap.SOAPMessage;
import javax.xml.transform.Transformer;
import javax.xml.transform.TransformerFactory;
import javax.xml.transform.dom.DOMSource;
import javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamResult;

import org.apache.ws.security.WSConstants;
import org.apache.ws.security.WSEncryptionPart;
import org.apache.ws.security.components.crypto.Crypto;
import org.apache.ws.security.components.crypto.PKCS11Device;
import org.apache.ws.security.message.WSSecHeader;
import org.apache.ws.security.message.WSSecSignature;
import org.apache.ws.security.message.WSSecTimestamp;
import org.w3c.dom.Document;
import org.xml.sax.InputSource;

public class ESign {

    String pin;
    String alias;
    Crypto crypto;
    Document signedDoc;

    public String getBatchStatus(String par1, String par2, String par3) {
        String sonuc = "";

        String soapReq = "<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?><soap:Envelope>"
                + ..................
                + "</soap:Envelope>";


        sign(soapReq, par1);    
    }

    public void sign(String XML, String par1) {
        try {

            PKCS11Device dv = new PKCS11Device();
            dv.slot = Integer.toString(slot);
            dv.drive = drive


            ClassLoader classLoader = EnvImz_BeratIsl.class.getClassLoader();
            dv.loadProperties(getCryptoProperties(), classLoader);

            crypto = dv;

            signDocument(xmlToDoc(XML));    
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {

        }
    }
    public Document xmlToDoc(String XML) {
        try {
            DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
            dbf.setNamespaceAware(true);
            DocumentBuilder db;
            db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
            InputSource is = new InputSource();
            is.setCharacterStream(new StringReader(XML));
            Document doc = db.parse(is);
            return doc;
        } catch (Exception e) {

        }
    }

    public void signDocument(Document doc) {
        try {
            WSSecSignature sig = new WSSecSignature();

            WSSecTimestamp time = new WSSecTimestamp();
            WSSecHeader header = new WSSecHeader();
            signedDoc = null;

            header.setMustUnderstand(true);
            sig.setSigCanonicalization("http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#");
            sig.setDigestAlgo("http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#sha256");
            sig.setSignatureAlgorithm("http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmldsig-more#rsa-sha256");
            sig.setUserInfo(alias, pin);
            sig.setKeyIdentifierType(WSConstants.BST_DIRECT_REFERENCE);
            header.insertSecurityHeader(doc);

            doc = time.build(doc, header);                      

            List<WSEncryptionPart> parts = new ArrayList<WSEncryptionPart>();
            WSEncryptionPart timestampPart = new WSEncryptionPart("Timestamp",
                    WSConstants.WSU_NS, "");
            WSEncryptionPart bodyPart = new WSEncryptionPart(
                    WSConstants.ELEM_BODY, WSConstants.URI_SOAP11_ENV, "");
            parts.add(timestampPart);
            parts.add(bodyPart);
            sig.setParts(parts);         

            sig.build(doc, crypto, header);
            signedDoc = doc;

        } catch (Exception e) {

        }
    }        
}
```

Error:

```
[ERROR] javax.xml.crypto.dsig.XMLSignatureException: java.security.InvalidKeyException: No installed provider supports this key: sun.security.pkcs11.P11Key$P11PrivateKey
    [ERROR] Exception occurred while trying to invoke service method getBatchStatus
    java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.axis2.rpc.receivers.RPCUtil.invokeServiceClass(RPCUtil.java:212)
        at org.apache.axis2.rpc.receivers.RPCMessageReceiver.invokeBusinessLogic(RPCMessageReceiver.java:117)
        at org.apache.axis2.receivers.AbstractInOutMessageReceiver.invokeBusinessLogic(AbstractInOutMessageReceiver.java:40)
        at org.apache.axis2.receivers.AbstractMessageReceiver.receive(AbstractMessageReceiver.java:114)
        at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.receive(AxisEngine.java:181)
        at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.HTTPTransportUtils.processHTTPPostRequest(HTTPTransportUtils.java:172)
        at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.AxisServlet.doPost(AxisServlet.java:146)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:646)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:220)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
        at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:501)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:170)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:98)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:950)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1040)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:607)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:315)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
    Caused by: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
        at org.apache.ws.security.message.WSSecSignature.computeSignature(WSSecSignature.java:561)
        at org.apache.ws.security.message.WSSecSignature.computeSignature(WSSecSignature.java:481)
        at org.apache.ws.security.message.WSSecSignature.build(WSSecSignature.java:386)
        at acron.EnvImz_BeratIsl.signDocument(EnvImz_BeratIsl.java:246)
        at acron.EnvImz_BeratIsl.soap_imzala(EnvImz_BeratIsl.java:178)
        at acron.EnvImz_BeratIsl.getBatchStatus(EnvImz_BeratIsl.java:288)
        ... 29 more
    Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Can't find bundle for base name org.apache.ws.security.errors, locale en_US
        at org.apache.ws.security.WSSecurityException.<clinit>(WSSecurityException.java:64)
        ... 35 more
    Caused by: java.util.MissingResourceException: Can't find bundle for base name org.apache.ws.security.errors, locale en_US
        at java.util.ResourceBundle.throwMissingResourceException(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.ResourceBundle.getBundleImpl(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.ResourceBundle.getBundle(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.ws.security.WSSecurityException.<clinit>(WSSecurityException.java:62)
        ... 35 more
```

Comment: can you share some code? start with `getBatchStatus` method

Answer (score 1):

`Can't find bundle for base name org.apache.ws.security.errors, locale en_US` your logger says that you have issue with locale in `ResourceBundle` you have to use

```
Locale locale = new Locale("en_US");
```

Answer (score 0):

This [one](https://community.oracle.com/thread/1528517) seems to address your problem, comes from the Oracle Support forum.